# Is any bounded sequence weakly precompact in a reflexive banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis

please help me to proov this property:
In a reflexive banach space any bounded sequence is weakly precompact

Answer (score 0):

Such a sequence is contained in a closed ball which by reflexivity is weakly compact, so as a subset of a weakly compact set, it is weakly pre-compact.

Comment: please explain more

Comment: Please explain which part you don't understand.

Comment: "Such a sequence is contained in a closed ball which by reflexivity is weakly compact"

Comment: see Banach-Bourbaki-Alaouglu's theorem