# Bounded but not weakly sequentially precompact sets

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

A subset $C$ of a Banach space $X$ is called weakly sequentially precompact if any sequence of points in $C$ has a subsequence weakly convergent to a point of $X$ (not $C$). We already know that weakly sequentially precompact sets are bounded (since weakly bounded implies bounded). **Is the converse true?**

I know this question is boring and I see no application of it. I'm only asking it for completeness. I haved looked it up on Internet but found no results. By Banach-Alaoglu any bounded set in dual space is weakly star precompact, this makes it hard to find an easy counterexample.

Comment: If the space is reflexive, yes. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058219/is-any-bounded-sequence-weakly-precompact-in-a-reflexive-banach-space) and [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem).
If the space is not reflexive, its closed unit ball is weakly closed but not weakly compact. For a concrete example, look at the standard unit vectors in $\ell_1$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you!